# PL/SQL Dynamic content is not displaying in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-19.1, oracle-apex-19.2

I am trying to display the results of a query in a region. However, the region just displays "New" and not the actual output. Could you please help?

PL/SQL code:

DECLARE

V_APP_COUNT NUMBER;
BEGIN

```
SELECT COUNT(*)  INTO V_APP_COUNT FROM APPLICATION;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_APP_COUNT);
```

END;

[image: Page designer with PL/SQL code]

[image: Display page]

Comment: dbms_output writes messages to a buffer - it is displayed on the screen in the developer tool ( eg sqldeveloper, sqlplus, sqlcl). It does *not* write messages to the http buffer. As @Littlefoot suggests, use the htp package to render html (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/w_htp.htm#BABGJJIH)

Comment: I want to display aggregate result in a card like region which is in APEX 20.2. How can I accomplish that here as there was only option for PL/SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Query you posted suits better to a report (pick any you want - interactive, classic or grid), not to PL/SQL Dynamic Content. It expects from you to actually "draw" the page using HTML code. Basically, your PL/SQL would use `htp.p` calls in order to display the result.

As I said - use a **report**.

Comment: I want to display aggregate result in a card like region which is in APEX 20.2. How can I accomplish that here as there was only option for PL/SQL.

Comment: "Card" is just another way to display a **classic report**. Once again: use a report, not PL/SQL dynamic content.

Comment: I used the classic report option but it is showing page numbers like 1-2 and some filtering option on the top. How to hide it?

Comment: "Numbers like 1-2" look like **pagination**; it is an option you can turn off in report's **attributes**. As of filtering, I don't know what it is. Classic reports don't have it by default (interactive reports do).